# Use calculated value as header in diagram

Tags: google-sheets

I created a diagram in Google Sheets to display a burndown chart. This will be copied and used as a template for each sprint, where every sprint will have its own sheet in the document.

So I would like to display the name of the current sheet as the title in the chart, to make it readable for all users, and will print nicely.

I have a script function that returns the name of the sheet, but I don't know the syntax to use a cell value or a function in the title of the diagram.

[image]

Comment: I think you'll need to use [getCharts()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcharts), [modify()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#modify()) and [chartbuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google can't use a formula to set the chart title. It has been requested. You can do it with script. This could be run onOpen.

```
function chartName() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName=sheet.getName()
  var nval="Burndown "+sheetName
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.modify()
  .setOption('title', nval || 'Empty')
  .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}
```